# Create Layer Package fails to execute -- error code 00045

Tags: arcmap, layer-package

I'm experiencing an error when I attempt to save a feature class as a Layer Package (.lpk) by right-clicking that feature class in my Table of Contents and selecting "Save As Layer File".

The Layer Package form pops up. After entering the required bits (namely summary and tags) and clicking "Analyze", I receive an error (code 00045) stating:

> A layer description is required for packaging

First, this field is not shown as required within the Layer Package form. Second and more importantly, even after entering a description, the error continues and prevents me from creating a Layer Package.

No amount of fiddling with the description will allow the layer package to be created. I can find no way around it. Esri's help page for code 00045 offers no assistance in remediating this particular problem, nor do I see that others are experiencing or have experienced it.

Can you suggest a remedy?

Answer (score 2):

You have not provided a picture of the General tab on your Layer Properties, or told us whether or not you have saved your map after setting a Description there.

[image]

To me the error seems well documented at [00045: A layer description is required for packaging](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/publish-map-services/00045-a-layer-description-is-required-for-packaging.htm).

I recommend double-checking the General tab of your Layer Properties and saving your map.  The latter may or may not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try naming the description of the layer prior to entering the layer package tool.

For some reason the tool does not recognize the layer description when entered into the tool, but does recognize it if it is entered beforehand.